# What values folder should I use for Galaxy S8+/S9+

Tags: java, android, xml, layout

I'm currently making a mobile application but I haven't managed to have my layout correctly displayed on `S8+/S9+`

I've used xxxhdpi folder but it didn't work

What should I do ?

Edit : I tried

`<meta-data android:name="android.max_aspect" android:value="2.1" />`

but it didn't works either

Answer (score 2):

Samsung S8+/S9+ have `18:9 aspect ratio`. To support these displays you don't need to create separate layout folders for that but set the **aspect ratio** in `AndroidManifest.xml` file under `<application>` element like below:

```
<meta-data android:name="android.max_aspect" android:value="2.1" />
```

This will inform to Android OS that your app can support maximum aspect ratio i.e. 18.5:9 which is almost same as Samsung S8+/S9+.

For more information check [this official blog](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2017/03/update-your-app-to-take-advantage-of.html).

**Update:**

Create separate layout folder i.e. `layout-swNNNdp` for Galaxy S8+/S9+. Here NNN is screen resolution of Galaxy S8+/S9+ devices (maybe `layout-sw1440dp` but please confirm). Copy your current layout xml file into `layout-swNNNdp` and modify it to fit on Galaxy S8+/S9+ devices.

For more info check [Providing alternative resources](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources#AlternativeResources)

**Note:**

`xxxhdpi` is for drawable resources not for layouts.

Comment: I put it under <manifest> </manifest> or under <application> </application> ?

And for the note, i was talking about values folder

Comment: Will try it tommorow and get back to you if it works or not ! :)

Comment: @Kryze this is the official way to handle Layouts for Galaxy S8+/S9+ devices. Its strange that it is not working. Could you please elaborate **It didn't works...**. What is not working? Are you getting any error?

Comment: When I put the resolution in WQHD it works, but when it is on FHD+ or HD+ the layout is a mess it's all I know, i can put screenshot if you want

Answer (score 1):

On my experience on S8+ you can use `drawable-xxhdpi` folder for your asset.

Cheers

Comment: It's for a layout, i used values-xxxhdpi but didn't worked, I have a Galaxy S5 which currently used xxhdpi is it the correct size or should I create a xhdpi for my Galaxy S5 and keep xxhdpi for the S8+/S9+ ?